# Как обьеденить два запроса на добавление связанные таблицы в PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE recruiter (
        nickname TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        url_account TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE proposal (
        header TEXT NOT NULL,
        time_addition TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        nickname TEXT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES recruiter (nickname)
);
```

И есть 2 запроса для добавления в одну и в другую по отдельности:

```
INSERT INTO recruiter (nickname, url_account) 
VALUES ('name_01', 'http://www.site.com');

INSERT INTO proposal (header, time_addition, nickname) 
VALUES ('welcome at work', now()::timestamp, 'name_01');
```

Мне надо как-то сделать все то-же самое одним запросом. Подскажите пожалуйста как их можно обьединить? Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем это делать одним запросом?

Comment: @plesser экономия времени.

Comment: Боюсь что не как.

Comment: @plesser вы уверены? Я тоже боюсь но все-же надеюсь...)

Comment: Ну вот сколько я рабтотаю с БД но такого не встречал. Я даже синтаксис себе не могу представить такой.

Comment: @plesser ок, не буду мучится тогда сделаю по отдельности. Спасибо что сказали.

Comment: **@plesser** Ну синтаксис представить несложно. Обновляемое представление на основе обеих таблиц... тем более есть общее  поле (они же не случайно и именами, и значениями совпадают, правда, ведь правда же, да?). Но смыслу и вправду - ноль. **Павел**, проверьте, коннектор, скорее всего, позволяет посылать серверу мультизапросы - так что два запроса можно отправить одним пакетом.

Comment: @Akina java.sql.Connection использую что-то тут такого не видно, но я еще поищу спасибо за подсказку. А к стати почему вы говорите что толку ноль? Разве 1 запрос это не всегда быстрее чем 2?

Comment: @Павел учитывая время работы одиночного insert, синтаксический разбор запроса занимает основное время. что бы произвести одновременно 2 вставки запрос будет сложным, и синтаксический анализатор потратит на него больше времени чем на 2 отдельных простых insert. P.S. очень надеюсь, что значения в кавычках у вас только для примера, а в программе на их месте плейсхолдеры и последующая связь переменных программы с ними. потому что передача параметров непосредственно в тексте запроса прямой способ снизить производительность

Comment: @Mike да это для примера, я обычно пробую запрос из шела чтобы понять не написал ли ерунды вот он и остался. А вот по поводу что лучше несколько простых запросов чем один сложный я не знал буду иметь в виду спасибо большое. И по поводу параметров в запросе тоже я так делаю иногда когда вариант только один, больше не буду. Спасибо.

Comment: @Павел *что-то тут такого не видно* Чего не видно? просто передайте сразу 2 запроса - сработает второй или нет?

Comment: @plesser Конкретно в postrgesql такой синтаксис есть (см. мой ответ),  но это думаю единственная СУБД, где такое возможно

Comment: @Akina не сразу 2 не проходит пишет ошибку синтаксиса но это через шэл.

Comment: При чём тут shell? и, кстати, там-то как раз просто обязано выполняться - что-то Вы не так делаете...

Comment: @Akina ну для начала в шеле потому что если там не сработает то через JDBC driver и тем более. Но я убрал `;` между запросами иначе это получится 2 запроса и мне падает ошибка синтаксиса на слове `INSERT` второго запроса. И с  `;` то точно сработает это понятно.

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы не делаете различия между "один запрос" и "одно обращение к серверу". Хотя это вещи разные. И, судя по неявно описанной цели, Вам нужно второе, хотя Вы бьётесь за первое. При этом решение с несколькими запросами в одной посылке будет работать и при бОльшем количестве таблиц, в то время как использование WITH при более чем 2 таблицах может стать проблематичным...

Comment: @Mike *в postrgesql такой синтаксис есть (см. мой ответ), но это думаю единственная СУБД, где такое возможно* MS SQL тоже умеет `WITH` применительно к `INSERT`, и у того есть `OUTPUT clause`... но вот сработает ли - надо пробовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH Q(nick) as(
 INSERT INTO recruiter (nickname, url_account) 
  VALUES ('name_01', 'http://www.site.com')
 RETURNING nickname
)
INSERT INTO proposal (header, time_addition, nickname) 
  values('welcome at work', now()::timestamp, 'name_01');
```

Последняя строка могла бы выглядеть как `SELECT 'welcome at work', now()::timestamp, nick from Q` и это было бы полезно, если бы в первой таблице был инкрементальный ID и надо было вставить его во вторую запись.

Если запись в таблице proposal должна всегда создаваться для любой новой записи из recruiter и тексты в полях этой записи статичны или могут быть как либо вычислены, то возможно стоило бы добавлять эту запись в триггере на таблице recruiter.

Так же от такой записи может быть польза, если второй insert не надо выполнять, если в первом произошел сбой. Например, такой ник уже есть в БД. Если выполнять 2 отдельных запроса и забыть проверять код завершения первого, то можно случайно вставить дополнительную запись в proposal к существующей ранее записи recruiter. В случае единого запроса это невозможно, либо запрос выполнится целиком, либо не выполнится ни одна его часть.

Что касается производительности, то выигрыш в скорости в такой ситуации от того, что запрос один сомнителен. Если он и есть то очень мал. И возможно не стоит усложнять код из за этого.